# Swift Package dependencies error- shell out

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone

The process function show error

[image: The process function show error]

I install updated shell out updated package , but i faced the Cannot find type 'Process' in scope. error

Answer (score 0):

`Process` and shell are not supported in iOS, those are macOS APIs.

Comment: `Process` is part of `Foundation` framework and is supported in iOS

Comment: As of March 2023, the [Process class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/) says it's only available in macOS and Mac Catalyst.